# LAG function in Alter Table produces windowed function error

Tags: sql-server

The following code works fine
    Select date_trans,time_trans,price,
    price - lag(price,1,0) over(order by date_tans ASC, time_trans ASC) As pChng
    From dbo.A_1

But if I try to alter the table and add a column with similar code I get an error. It seams to me the windowed function is inside an order by clause, so I don't understand why the error

```
Alter table dbo.A_1 Add pChng as price - lag(price,1,0) over(order by date_trans ASC, time_trans ASC)
```

Comment: Sorry you can't use windowed functions in a computed column.  Here's the MSDN page which details what you can and cannot do.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add that as a computed column.

You could either

- Add a scalar UDF that accepts parameters for date_trans and  time_trans and then returns the price of the preceding row and reference that in a computed column.
- Or just create a view with your `lag` column.
- Or use triggers to maintain the `pChng` column yourself.

The three options have various trade offs between efficiency and implementation complexity. The first one will likely be much less efficient than the second if doing a query against the whole table for example.